# Django REST + Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I want to use this chain (*Angular*, not AngularJS) but don't quite understand how exactly it should work in production. Tutorials and simple logic show two variants:

1. Separate application servers, for example

   - Apache
   - Angular on top of Webpack or something
   - Django on top of Gunicorn
2. "Folder-style" project separation, like

   ```
   project-folder\
       angular-folder\
           ...
       django-folder\
           ...
      (some config to make it work)
   ```

Does anybody have working boilerplate of such an application? Everything I saw was outdated. Can someone show the right path and where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This wonderful blog post](http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework) by Jonathan Cox introduced me to the use of Django Webpack Loader, a Django app that reads a webpack stats file and loads the required bundles automatically. It focuses on React, but the idea can be applied to any front-end framework that uses webpack as output, I used Vue with great success.

Basically, your development stack will look like this:

1. Webpack Dev Server or Express for serving your bundle with hot reload.
2. Django Dev Server, using the webpack loader's template tags to load the bundle from Express' virtual location.

Then in production:

1. Use Webpack to build the bundle straight to Django's Static folder
2. Load the bundle from statics, using webpack loader.

Folder structure should be whatever you want, you can separate both code bases or make a new folder at app-level in your Django project to keep it all together. It shouldn't matter, while you can point to the dist folder with `STATICFILES`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've thought about production-mode with bundle in `STATICFILES` but Django Webpack Loader is something completly new to me.